# CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage return -6683(kCVReturnPixelBufferNotOpenGLCompatible)

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, yuv

I had extract Y U V data from video frame separately and saved them in `data[0],data[1],data[2];`The frame size is `640*480;`Now I creat the `pixelBuffer` as below:

```
void *pYUV[3] = {data[0], data[1], data[2]};
size_t planeWidth = {640, 320, 320};
size_t planeHeight = {480, 240, 240};
size_t planeBytesPerRow = {640, 320, 320};
CVReturn renturn = CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                   640, 
                                   480,
                                   kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange, 
                                   nil,
                                   nil,
                                   3, 
                                   pYUV,
                                   planeWidth,
                                   planeHeight, 
                                   planeBytesPerRow, 
                                   nil,
                                   nil, nil, &_pixelBuffer);
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(_pixelBuffer, 0);
CVPixelBufferRetain(_pixelBuffer);
    // Periodic texture cache flush every frame
CVOpenGLESTextureCacheFlush(_textureCache, 0);

// The Buffer cannot be used with OpenGL as either its size, pixelformat or attributes are not supported by OpenGL
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
CVReturn err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                                            _textureCache,
                                                            _pixelBuffer,
                                                            NULL,
                                                            GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                            GL_LUMINANCE,
                                                            im.width,
                                                            im.height,
                                                            GL_LUMINANCE,
                                                            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                            0,
                                                            &_yTexture);

if (!_yTexture || err) {
    NSLog(@"CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage failed (error: %d)", err);  
    return;
}
glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(_yTexture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(_yTexture));
 CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(_pixelBuffer, 0);
```

But the err is -6638, the documentation simply states that "The pixel buffer is not compatible with OpenGL due to an unsupported buffer size, pixel format, or attribute." which does not help me much.

How can I fixed it?

Comment: I got the same error. Any progress?

Answer (score 2):

Does your source image/video frame have a resolution which is a power of 2? If not, you must resize it before creating the texture.

Answer (score 2):

Apple details the cause of this exact issue in [Technical Q&A 1781](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1781/_index.html)

The issue is that the source pixel buffer must be IOSSurface backed. Specify an empty dictionary as the value in `kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey`